# Failed to install the ADT (Android Development Toolkit) in Titanium Studio (Appcelerator)?

Tags: android, eclipse, titanium, adt

I'm trying to install the ADT to Titanium Studio, I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   15.0.0.v201110251216-213216 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216)

The versions I'm using are:

- Titanium Studio, build: 1.0.7.201112152014
- ADT-15.0.0

Titanium Studio is based on Eclipse, where you can install this plugin perfectly.

How can the ADT be successfully integrated with Titanium Studio?

Comment: Usually, when you say "I get the following error", you include that error...

Comment: Really? You edited it, but couldn't be bothered to add the actual error?

Comment: Sorry! I update the question.

Comment: Just so you know that ADT is not required for Android development with Titanium. Only the SDK must be installed to use Titanium Studio for Android development with Titanium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Eclipse Indigo Update Site

Go to Help > Install New Software > Available Software Sites and select checkbox to enable Eclipse Indigo Update Site